# Where to copy custom openssl engine library in openssl 1.1.0

Tags: openssl

Am working in Ubuntu 18.04 with openssl 1.1.0g version. I built a custom openssl engine and now i want to use this engine instead of default openssl engine.

My engine library name is `libstoreengine.so` and i copied this to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.0/engines/` path.

When i run my application the it says Store Engine not found. There is path issue here, am i copying the library in right path? I copied my library in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` still am getting same error.

Please let me know the right path where i have to copy this engine?

Comment: Please can you post the output from the command `openssl version -a`. Please also post the exact error message that you get.

Comment: `OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
platform: debian-amd64
compiler: gcc -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_THREADS -DOPENSSL_NO_STATIC_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPADLOCK_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DOPENSSLDIR="\"/usr/lib/ssl\"" -DENGINESDIR="\"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1\"" 
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1"
`

Comment: I copied my libstoreengine.so in to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1` also, still am getting same error

Comment: Please post the exact error that you get

Comment: Problem Solved: I copied my libstoreengine.so file in to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1 and renamed it as "storeengine.so"